# program in c with strings

Tags: c, string

I have a problem with this code. I need to scan strings until I give the char `0` and count how many words with 1 char, 2, 3 ... etc. Here is my code, but it never stops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char a[100];
   int length[14],i,k;
   for (i=1; i<=14; i++)
      length[i]=0;

   do
   {
      scanf("%s",a);
      length[strlen(a)] =length[strlen(a)]+1;
   } while (a!="0");

   printf("Word Length\t|Number of Occurs\n");
   for(i=1; i<=14; i++)
   {
      printf("%d\t\t|",i);
      if (length[i]>=1)
         for (k=1; k<=length[i]; k++)
            printf("*");

      printf("\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot check whether two strings are equal/different using ==/!= operators.
In C, string is array of characters and name of the array represents its **address**, so in your example, comparing *a* with "0" simply compares adress of array *a* and address of string "0" (which is probably address in the fixed area called string pool, depending on the compiler you use) which will never be the same, that's why your program enters an infinite loop.
You should use *strcmp* function form *string.h*

Comment: This is just one of the problem. There are several other problems too. OP's code invokes UB.